# Extracting types of properties of generic interfaces still requires unnecessary generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

When I have an interface with a generic as such:

```
   interface I1<S> {
      a: string;
      b: genericType<S>
}
```

and try to extract type of property `a` using `I1['a']`, typescript throws the following error:

`TS2314: Generic type 'I1<S>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

Should this not be fine since the extracted property type is not actually dependent on `<S>`? Either I am failing to understand how Typescript actually works or this should indeed be okay.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property `a` type is not reliant on `S`, but you cannot omit the type parameter as part of the  [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types). Some options:

1.) Set `S` to `unknown`

```
type T1 = I1<unknown>["a"] // string
```

2.) Declare a default for `S` in the interface

```
interface I2<S = unknown> {
  a: string;
  b: S
}

type T2 = I2["a"] // string
```

3.) Keep it generic

```
type T3<S> = I1<S>["a"]  // T3<S> = string
// doesn't make too much sense in this particular case
```

[Here is a sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=101&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEYA8BlAfMgbwFgAoZZOALmQGcwpQBzAblPICNrtSBfU00JFiIUqAEw5kAXmQBXEAGsQAewDuIfMTIVqdBiBZtknZNxJ8SpMAE8ADigAq6aWizylajQG0ARHB8AusgA9MG09ExWdo5iLuK%20-kGh4fqM-CQ29sgOAMw4%20DIY%20QmBIWHKUMgKEBC2yMBgyIwQINDACMgAFAAmyhA0IADkjQC2cNXIYMrKyCOyCAAWtC00KAvQEAA0FDTI1sqyyABWsnTItu0KFACU6elAA)

Comment: Thanks. So if i understand correctly TS has to instantiate the interface before accessing its members?

Comment: In `type T1 = I1<unknown>["a"]`, `I1<unknown>["a"]` is actually a [type reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#382-type-references), where all type arguments have to be supplied in order to use it as an actual type (it is called instantiating of the generic type; [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#37-named-types) might be also interesting for you). Hope, that helps.